# How to save List<KeyValuePairs<int,object>> as a SQLite table?

Tags: c#, list, sqlite, xamarin, android-sqlite

I have a List of key value pairs, but I'm not sure how I can save it in SQLite.
I've downloaded the library, and created a database. I know how to save objects, but how do I save the **List<KeyValuePair<int,object>>** into a table?

Comment: you can't really save an arbitrary object to a table unless you serialize it.

Comment: You could look at serializing the object to JSON and then storing it in a column of type TEXT with the other column being an integer.

Comment: is this something that really needs to be stored relationally, or could you just serialize it to a file?

Comment: This is a list I need to access every time I open an activity. For each time the method runs, it's running 2 nested loops over 300 items in an array. So, I figured storing the result once into SQLite and accessing it from would be a more optimal solution. However, I'm open for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the int in a column and the object in another column. Or instead of using a keyvaluePair, you could add a int property to your object.
Then you can save it something like:

```
    public void Insert(Product product)
    {
        using SQLiteConnection sqliteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(GetConnectionString());
        sqliteConnection.Execute("insert into Products (Name, Price, Quantity) values (@Name,  @Price, @Quantity)", product);
    }
```

Here, I save just some properties from my product object in the db.

Comment: I could definitely just have added an int property to this. Thanks!